# Apache Server Timing Out taking long time

Tags: apache, cloudflare, server-side-attacks

i was in in trouble help me by figuring out the problem I've run my website on my Apache server for quite some time now and recently ran into an issue that has me stumped.

My server has been DDOS attacked in the past requiring me to move my server behind a proxy/WAF. For some time I was behind Sucuri as it provided the best affordable defense at the time. The attacks tapered off and I moved to Cloudflare free to protect my IP address while lightening up on my monthly server costs. The switch was smooth and everything has been working fine for several months.

I was recently hit again with what seemed to be a layer 7 attack. I could see several IP addresses making 10-20 requests every couple of seconds in my domain's access.log. Running netstat returned thousands of TIME_WAIT and SYN_RECV all with Cloudflare IP addresses. This lead me to believe the attack was against my domain, being proxied by Cloudflare, and reaching my server regardless of my security settings. I confirmed this by viewing the statistics provided by Cloudflare and seeing millions of requests being made in a short time period. Unfortunately this is making it even more difficult to pinpoint the attack. what should i do.

I've enabled syn cookies, added mod_cloudflare to Apache, activated Cloudflare's WAF / rate limiting rules, blocked offending IP addresses, and used mod_evasive to automatically blacklist future offenders. This has reduced (and almost stopped) the amount of malicious requests seen in the Apache access log but has not resolved the timeouts.check [site](https://earningkart.in)

According to Cloudflare analytics, I've only received 16,000 requests in the previous 6 hours (as opposed to the tens of millions when I was being actively attacked) but I get timeouts on every other request (even directly connecting, without Cloudflare).
Thanks

Comment: your help would be appreciated

Comment: You've told quite a story about your adventures and how you don't like paying for stuff - but then given very specific stats disproving that your current issue has got anything to do with the history (apart from trying to save money). i.e.you've given us lots of irrelevant information, and nothing on which to formulate an opinion on the current issue. As posed the question is off-topic on StackOverflow (although I suspect the underlying reason is code related). Voting to close.

Comment: i don't know why downvoted? this is a good question and its answers valueable to me

Answer (score 1):

Boost proxy server security and defend against DoS attacks by blocking unsolicited packets or by using load balancers, as these actions could help reduce the impact the attack has on the server.

There are also attacks that use a proxy server on the Internet as a transit device to hide the originating source of the attack on your network. Blocking open or malicious proxy servers from accessing the network or servers is one way to prevent this type of attack from being successful

i Hope this will definitely help you

Comment: check this answer on stackexchange [https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67057/why-do-i-target-the-proxy-server-if-i-send-a-ddos-attack-from-it](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67057/why-do-i-target-the-proxy-server-if-i-send-a-ddos-attack-from-it)

Comment: thanks smith for your value able answer it helps me a little bit